# How does runBlocking supply a default value for context?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-coroutines

I am learning [Kotlin coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine). The first code example is:

```
fun main() = runBlocking { ... }
```

The [signature for `runBlocking`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Builders.kt#L38) is:

```
public actual fun <T> runBlocking(context: CoroutineContext, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): T
```

There is no default value specified for `context`. How is `context` supplied without me specifying it and with no default specified?

Comment: Interestingly, [there was a default `EmptyCoroutineContext` in 1.5.2](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/1.5.2/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Builders.kt). Maybe some code generation is involved around this

Comment: you need to look at the function with `expect` https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/concurrent/src/Builders.concurrent.kt

Comment: @IR42 oh I had missed the `actual` right there. That explains it. I think you should put it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joffrey is correct that the default value is `EmptyCoroutineContext`. You can see in [the latest commit as of writing](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/commit/042720589c6f438f77d84254bd2dceb569f01841#diff-b3fba6d7a05a6492006fcb40aaae78396bfa844450095c9ddb41c11024c7e453) the default value was removed.

You can see in that commit, the function was changed to `actual fun`, probably in support of some multiplatform changes per the commit message. If you have an `expect fun` with a default argument, and you also try adding it to the `actual fun` you get the error

> Actual function cannot have default argument values, they should be declared in the expected function

The `expect fun` declaration is in [`Builders.concurrent.kt`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/042720589c6f438f77d84254bd2dceb569f01841/kotlinx-coroutines-core/concurrent/src/Builders.concurrent.kt), defined with the `EmptyCoroutineContext`